# Error while saving a pandas DataFrame to a feather file, using to_feather() function

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I am trying to save a pandas dataframe to a feather file using a pandas function **.to_feather()** as shown below;
`df.to_feather("D:\{}.feather".format(parms['table_or_view_name']))`

But I am getting an error pointing to pyarrow library, please be noted that I have already upgraded the pyarrow to the most recent build(7.0.0), despite that I am still facing the same issue:

```
ArrowInvalid                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-5459a546a0cb> in <module>
----> 1 df.to_feather("D:\{}.feather".format(parms['table_or_view_name']))

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    205                 else:
    206                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 207             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    208 
    209         return cast(F, wrapper)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in to_feather(self, path, **kwargs)
   2517         from pandas.io.feather_format import to_feather
   2518 
-> 2519         to_feather(self, path, **kwargs)
   2520 
   2521     @doc(

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\feather_format.py in to_feather(df, path, storage_options, **kwargs)
     85         path, "wb", storage_options=storage_options, is_text=False
     86     ) as handles:
---> 87         feather.write_feather(df, handles.handle, **kwargs)
     88 
     89 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\feather.py in write_feather(df, dest, compression, compression_level, chunksize, version)
    152 
    153     if _pandas_api.is_data_frame(df):
--> 154         table = Table.from_pandas(df, preserve_index=False)
    155 
    156         if version == 1:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\table.pxi in pyarrow.lib.Table.from_pandas()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\pandas_compat.py in dataframe_to_arrays(df, schema, preserve_index, nthreads, columns, safe)
    592 
    593     if nthreads == 1:
--> 594         arrays = [convert_column(c, f)
    595                   for c, f in zip(columns_to_convert, convert_fields)]
    596     else:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\pandas_compat.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    592 
    593     if nthreads == 1:
--> 594         arrays = [convert_column(c, f)
    595                   for c, f in zip(columns_to_convert, convert_fields)]
    596     else:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\pandas_compat.py in convert_column(col, field)
    579             e.args += ("Conversion failed for column {!s} with type {!s}"
    580                        .format(col.name, col.dtype),)
--> 581             raise e
    582         if not field_nullable and result.null_count > 0:
    583             raise ValueError("Field {} was non-nullable but pandas column "

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\pandas_compat.py in convert_column(col, field)
    573 
    574         try:
--> 575             result = pa.array(col, type=type_, from_pandas=True, safe=safe)
    576         except (pa.ArrowInvalid,
    577                 pa.ArrowNotImplementedError,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\array.pxi in pyarrow.lib.array()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\array.pxi in pyarrow.lib._ndarray_to_array()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\error.pxi in pyarrow.lib.check_status()

ArrowInvalid: ('cannot mix list and non-list, non-null values', 'Conversion failed for column Resources with type object')
```

Note:
This error only occurs when I try to save the file as to_feather(), but when I tried to save the dataframe as .to_json() it worked.

Please suggest if there is any workaround for this error, thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems the "Ressource" column of your DF contains data in formats that are not compatible with feather format. What's inside that column? Just from the message error, it seems there are lists and other stuff there.

Comment: Hi @VicN,

We actually have JSON objects stored in (Resource) column,
example: 
`{'VerticaBucketManagementPolicy': {'Properties': {'PolicyDocument': {'Statement': [{'Action': 's3:*', 'Effect': 'Allow', 'Resource': ....]}}}`

Comment: Well, that's weird. It's hard to debug this without actually looking at the whole data, sorry.

Comment: According to the error message, your JSON objects have a field which mixes lists and scalar values, which is not supported in the default conversion to arrow.

Comment: @VicN, alright I am currently raising appropriate exceptions for the dataframe cols which are containing any datatype(s) other than int64/32 and float64/32, and am exploring how to load or explode the data into additional columns based on their structure, or drop those cols, etc., lets see...

Comment: Arrow will require that your columns be homogenous.  That is, each column can have a different type but any particular column must be a single type.  This error occurs when you have a column that is mixing two different types of data (and Arrow can't find a least common type ancestor).  Here is a very minimal example of this: https://gist.github.com/westonpace/7cc7bdb214c5f3749718c8044f2cba14

You will need to figure out where in your data you have something like that example.